# Stack Memory during Runtime

Tags: java, memory, stack

How do I get Stack's Maximum memory during runtime. My understanding is that Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() will give heap memory. I want to know the stack memory.

p.s: I've set -xss as 1m, I wanna test this, so I'm open to suggestions if there is a better way to find that than getting it from the running instance itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JConsole available in JDK_HOME/bin/jconsole.exe to check the statistics about your program. It will show both Heap/Non-Heap and detailed heap memory usage with graphs.

Comment: Non-heap memory is nothing but stack.

Comment: I always though non-heap included direct memory, gui components, memory used by the jvm for internal processing etc.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think so too.

Comment: @Vitthal I'll check it though thanx.

Comment: @PeterLawrey GUI components are also object so accordingly they will get loaded in Heap. For JVM internal use e.g. to load classes it uses PermGen Space which is again reserved part of heap. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Vitthal GUI components on the heap are proxies for the real graphics objects which are usually in native memory. Similarly for Sockets and direct ByteBuffers.  The JVM loads code into the perm gen/meta space but everything else use native memory.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you usually care about as typically you want to avoid recursion in Java as using a loop is usually more efficient (Java doesn't have tail call optimisation for example)

On Linux you can work this out by reading `/proc/self/maps` which has all the memory mapping the program is using and there is an entry for each stack.

e.g. in this example you can see the stack area for thread 669 and 668

```
7ff4617ee000-7ff4617f1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff4617f1000-7ff4618ef000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:669]
7ff4618ef000-7ff4618f2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff4618f2000-7ff461bf0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:668]
```

The size of this range in hex is `0xFE000` or 1040384 which is almost 1 MB.

Comment: The recursion is being done while deserializing rmi object which I've no control over. And I'm on Windows.

Comment: @Cybermonk You could measuring it empirically by recursing until you throw a StackOverflowError and count how long this is.  If you do this for a known size e.g. 1 MB, you could estimate it e.g. if it recurses 2x as long it might be about 2 MB.